# Javascript how to fix copy sec text

Tags: javascript

Copy Selected Text
Often you may have some information on your page that your visitors might want to copy. You can make it easier for them by providing a mechanism that allows them to simply click a button to do so. First you need to paste this code into the head of your web page:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function copyit(theField) {
    var selectedText = document.selection;
    if (selectedText.type == 'Text') {
        var newRange = selectedText.createRange();
        theField.focus();
        theField.value = newRange.text;
    } else {
        alert('select a text in the page and then press this button');
    }
}
</script>
And in the body of your web page, add the following where you want the text to appear:
<form name="it">
<div align="center">
<input onclick="copyit(this.form.select1)" type="button" value="Press to copy the highlighted text" name="btnCopy">
<p>
<textarea name="select1" rows="4" cols="45"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't deface posts, even ones you created.

Answer (score 4):

In order to find an intersection point, you need to keep track of the places you've visited. Your game state is currently just tracking the current location. You could add to that a Set of the locations you've visited and a List of intersections (of course, in a real snake game, an intersection may be handled as a Game Over instead, but it sounds like you just want to know what intersections occurred).

```elm
type alias State =
    { loc : Location
    , visited : Set ( Int, Int ) -- this is a tuple because Elm needs a comparable type
    , intersections : List Location
    }
```

Now you'll need to update the move functionality to keep track of the locations that were visited, and if this move intersects a previously visited location, keep track of that as well:

```elm
move : Char -> State -> State
move action state =
    let
        newLoc =
            case action of
                '^' ->
                    { x = state.loc.x, y = state.loc.y + 1 }

                'v' ->
                    { x = state.loc.x, y = state.loc.y - 1 }

                '>' ->
                    { x = state.loc.x + 1, y = state.loc.y }

                '<' ->
                    { x = state.loc.x - 1, y = state.loc.y }

                _ ->
                    state.loc

        newIntersections =
            if Set.member ( newLoc.x, newLoc.y ) state.visited then
                newLoc :: state.intersections
            else
                state.intersections
    in
    { state
        | loc = newLoc
        , visited = Set.insert ( newLoc.x, newLoc.y ) state.visited
        , intersections = newIntersections
    }
```

Calculating the first intersection could be done similar to finding the last position (by using a fold), but in this case your fold function can halt when it reaches the first intersection:

```elm
calculateNextIntersection : String -> State -> Maybe Location
calculateNextIntersection actions state =
    let
        haltAtIntersection char state =
            if List.isEmpty state.intersections then
                move char state
            else
                state

        final =
            actions
                |> String.toList
                |> List.foldl haltAtIntersection state
    in
    List.head final.intersections
```

Working example [here on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/MgfLczxw8ba1).